# Camera driver, updated or removed and now isn't working

Tags: raspbian, camera, driver, modules, libcamera

My camera was working fine, but now it isn't being recognized anymore.
I tried to check if it was enabled on the Raspberry Configuration Interface tab, but the camera option isn't showing anymore.
On the raspi-config menu it also changed and now only appears the legacy camera option.
Looks like my driver was uninstalled somehow. I can't find any info about where to download a new one, the only advices I find its to use sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get full upgrade/sudo apt-get upgrade. None of them works. I tried to use libcamera-still to take one photo.
Screenshots :
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using Raspberry Pi OS Buster or Bullseye? What camera are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bullseye (version 11) and my camera is OV5647

Comment: Try using Buster or the new Legacy version.